# error is The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Pls can anyone assist me out with this.I have been stucked on it for hours

url is "https://pryaniky.com/static/json/sample.json"

[image of my model.swift[image]
I can't seem to understand why its not in the correct format..
I will highly appreciate any assistance.
thanks in anticipation

Comment: Instead of posting image of your code you should add your code as Code. Also you need to show us your [Empty] Model.

Comment: `print("error is \(error)")` instead of using `localizedDescription`.

Comment: here is my Empty model
struct Empty: Codable {
    var data: [Datum]?
    var view: [String]?
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var data: DataClass?
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    var text: String?
    var url: String?
    var selectedID: Int?
    var variants: [Variant]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text, url
        case selectedID
        case variants
    }
}

// MARK: - Variant
struct Variant: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var text: String?
}

Comment: Hi Larme.   I got this when I used print("error is \(error)"                                                                error is typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it
My bad

just changed [Empty] to Empty in the ApiHandler